# Seekbar visibility callback with AVPlayerViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, avplayerviewcontroller

AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate specifically provides this method for tvOS 11+ version. Is something similar available for iOS to get the visibility status of control bar on iOS?

```
optional func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, willTransitionToVisibilityOfTransportBar visible: Bool, with coordinator: AVPlayerViewControllerAnimationCoordinator)
```